# Updating Facebook Graph API to v2.0 or higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

We have developed a Social Media Marketing tool, which we had to update to Graph API v2.0 now.

Unfortunately, the v2.0 and higher include some changes, which have a terrible effect on our software.

As far as I understand, it's no longer possible to search for public posts. Also you may no longer request your own friends, as well as their public timeline. Also, it's no longer possiblie to query the public timeline or any public data by foreign persons. Another problem is that the username field is no longer available, so it will not work anymore to query the id of a user by the username. Is there any other way to do this?
And is it possible to get the feed via RSS?

Does anyone know whether these changes are final? Our existing software is dependent on this data. We develop it for 2 years and have customers who use our software. Does anyone have a similar problem and a solution for it?

Is there any statement from Facebook, why they made these API changes?

I'm very grateful about answers.

Christine

Comment: All those changes are done for different reasons. No there is no other way to do it. They removed those features

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WizKid. What about the Public Feed API? How can I get access to it? It's very important to us. The existence of our software and also of our Startup depends on it.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed it say: "Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time."